# How to connect mysql kubernetes container internally with nodejs k8s container?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, service, kubernetes

I have created mysql k8s container and nodejs k8s container under same namespace.I can't able to connect mysql db.(sequalize)

I have tried to connect using '''http://mysql.e-commerce.svc.cluster.local:3306'''.But i got "SequelizeHostNotFoundError" error.

Here is my service and deployment yaml files.

````
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
   app: mysql
 name: mysql
 namespace: e-commerce
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    nodePort: 30306
  selector:
    app: mysql
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: e-commerce
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql-container
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim```
````

Comment: please share with your results - did try the solution below?

Comment: Hi Mithun, It would be nice to upvote/accept the most useful answer in the thread. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access database with http protocol, leave it or change with mysql://ip:3306. Some clients won't accept DNS name for databases so you can check ClusterIP of service and try that IP too.

Answer (score 2):

From the ClusterIP worked for me or better way to go with the host name of the local cluster service ex. `db-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local`. This way if you cluster restarts and your IP changes, then you got it covered.

[image]

Comment: can you please point to a doc explaining about this `db-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local` more in detail?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by community member [FL3SH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57466395/how-to-connect-mysql-kubernetes-container-internally-with-nodejs-k8s-container/57466481#57466481) you can change your `spec.type` to `clusterIP`.
You can reproduce this task using stable helm chart [wordpress/mysql](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/wordpress).
For newly created pods:

```
mysql-mariadb-0
mysql-wordpress
```

and services:

```
mysql-mariadb
mysql-wordpress
```

After successfully deployment you can verify if your service is working from the `mysql-wordpress` pod by running:

```
kubectl exec -it mysql-wordpress-7cb4958654-tqxm6 -- /bin/bash
```

In addition, you can install additional tools like nslooukp, telnet:

`apt-get update && apt-get install dnsutils telnet`

Services and connectivity with db you can test by running f.e. those commands:

```
nslookup mysql-mariadb
telnet mysql-mariadb 3306
mysql -uroot -hmysql-mariadb -p<your_db_password>
```

example output:

```
nslookup mysql-mariadb  
Server:         10.125.0.10
Address:        10.125.0.10#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mysql-mariadb.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.125.0.76


mysql -u root -hmysql-mariadb -p<your_db_password>
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 2068
Server version: 10.1.40-MariaDB Source distribution
```

You should be able to connect using service name or using ip address.
Inside this helm chart you can find also template for statefulset in order to create mysql pods.

**Update**

From the second pod f.e. ubuntu run this example - [Node.js Mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp),  install nodes.js and create connection to the database **demo_db_connection.js**

example:

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "mysql-mariadb",
      user: "root",
      password: "yourpassword"
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
    });
```

run it:

```
root@ubuntu:~/test# node demo_db_connection.js
Connected!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
   app: mysql
 name: mysql
 namespace: e-commerce
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
```

with the same connection string.

Comment: Are you sure that connection url is correct - I mean the syntax? Try with just service name so url will be `http://mysql:3306'

Comment: Curl command inside nodejs container also not helps.Its in KIND(kubernetes in Docker)

Comment: when I tried the wget command inside nodejs container.-->
Connecting to mysql:3306 (10.244.0.4:3306)
wget: bad header line: 5.6.45

Comment: Now try to install mysql client in nodejs container and connect to the database.

Comment: Before I used node:10-alpine image as base image of my node cont..Now I changed to node:10.14.2..I got ```5.6.45o%cHzQf/??Q.1Kf>Aju.!Zmysql_native_password!??#08S01Got packets out of order``` when i put curl sql string.

Comment: Try `mysql://ip:3306` as @Akın Özer suggested.

Comment: You cannot use `curl` to verify connectivity with database, you have to use `mysql` for it.